# When answering someone what does a company take? Whose/which/what?

Tags: pronouns

I just had conversation with my friend and got stuck in answering.

> Hey, do you know? I bought a 4K 3D TV 
>  ~Wow, which company's? 
>  ~Sony, ***whose else?***

Is that correct? Since the question was asked with apostrophe, I had to answer with 'whose.'

Are 'which and what' also possible? Though I don't think so!

Comment: I think it's better to say it like this *-- Wow! What brand? -- Sony! What else?*

Comment: I don't have any control over the question, Michael! :) @MichaelRybkin And at least in India, it'd be wow... *which brand* for sure!

Comment: Technically, the final line of your dialogue should be "Sony's, who else's?" since the "wow" question took a possessive form. ;)

Answer (score 2):

When we want to make a possessive using a pronoun followed by the adverb *else*, we normally put the possessive 'S' after the whole noun phrase:

- anybody else's
- noone else's
- who else's?

However, it used to be more common to use a genitive pronoun and put the word *else* afterwards:

- anybody's else
- noone's else
- whose else?

Although this is rare now, it is still seen occasionally, even in print.

This was remarked upon by the famous grammarian of English, Otto Jespersen. Here is an excerpt from one of his works (*A Modern English Grammar on Historical Principles, Vol 6* 1940-49):

[image]